# How do you create a table in jQuery using html user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm pretty junior, so I'm unsure on if I worded the question properly.

I'm looking to create a textbox in HTML where the user can input the amount of columns and rows for the table.  From there I need to use Javascript/Jquery to create the table when the button is clicked.

So far I have been able to create the text boxes.  I capture the inputed numbers into variables, and created two for loops.

It doesn't work... :/

```
<body>

        Set Rows:<br>
        <input type="text" id="setRows">
        <br>
        Set Columns:<br>
        <input type="text" id="setColumns">

    <button type='button' onclick='myForm()'>Create Table</button>
    <p id = "demo1"></p>
    <p id = "demo2"></p>

</body>
```

---

```
function myForm()
{
    var setRows = document.getElementById("setRows").value;
    //document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = setRows;

    var setColumns = document.getElementById("setColumns").value;
    //document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = setColumns;


}

$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("button").click(function()
    {
        $("<table></table>").insertAfter("p:last");

        for (i = 0; i < setRows; i++)
        {
            $("<tr></tr>").appendTo("table");
        }

        for (i = 0; i < setColumns; i++)
        {
            $("<td>column</td>").appendTo("tr");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Sidenote: I find it odd that you're using plain JS in your `myForm()` function but jQuery everywhere else. Also, for tables, it should be a pair of nested for loops, not two separate ones. Right now, it will add x number of `<tr></tr>` elements, followed by x number of `<td>...</td>` elements.

Comment: The problem is `var setRows` defines a variable in the scope of `myForm` which isn't accessible anywhere else. Why bother setting the `onclick` handler in HTML anyway? You're defining the click handler in the `$("button").click` call. Just call `myForm()` there. Move the `var` declarations outside the function definition.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you're setting the variables `setRows` and `setColumns` in a different function from the one that uses them. You should do everything in one function -- either bind it with the `onclick` attribute or with `$("button").click()` -- rather than splitting it into separate functions.

I also think it would be clearer to use nested loops to make it more obvious that you're adding cells to each row. `appendTo()` will automatically clone the object being appended if there are multiple targets, but this is an obscure feature (I'm very experienced with jQuery and didn't know about it until now) that isn't so obvious.  It will also make the code easier to extend if you need to put different values in each cell (e.g. filling them from an array of data, or initializing with something like "row I col J").

```js
function myForm() {
  var setRows = $("#setRows").val();
  var setColumns = $("#setColumns").val();
  var table = $("<table>").insertAfter("p:last");
  for (var i = 0; i < setRows; i++) {
    var row = $("<tr>");
    for (var j = 0; j < setColumns; j++) {
      $("<td>column</td>").appendTo(row);
    }
    table.append(row);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Set Rows:<br>
        <input type="text" id="setRows">
        <br>
        Set Columns:<br>
        <input type="text" id="setColumns">

    <button type='button' onclick='myForm()'>Create Table</button>
    <p id = "demo1"></p>
    <p id = "demo2"></p>
```

Comment: Did you try it without nesting? `.appendTo("tr")` worked for me.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you close your `</tr>` or `</table>` - am I missing something?

Comment: @Adjit It's unnecessary when you're creating elements with jQuery.

Comment: @Adjit See https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2. When creating new elements, the closing tag is optional.

Comment: Why do you (and others) insist that "nested loop" is required. It's working just fine without a nested loop. Optimal? maybe not, but the output is the same.

Comment: @Mackan I didn't realize until these comments that `appendTo()` will automatically clone the element if there are multiple targets.

Comment: But I still prefer the nested loops, because it expresses the logic better. Also, it generalizes better to multiple tables, or if you need to put distinct contents into each cell.

Comment: @Barmar Agreed - I just noticed that others jumped on the "nested requirement" train and thought I'd at least comment on it :) Hope people revise false statements at least

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are created in a function (setRows and setColumns), so they are not available outside of this function. Define them globally if you want the "myForm" function to remain (it's not needed though).

Check this quick example, keeping your code intact:

```js
var setRows = 0;
var setColumns = 0;

function myForm() {
  //setRows = document.getElementById("setRows").value;
  setRows = $('#setRows').val();
  //setColumns = document.getElementById("setColumns").value;
  setColumns = $('#setColumns').val();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("<table></table>").insertAfter("p:last");
    for (i = 0; i < setRows; i++) {
      $("<tr></tr>").appendTo("table");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < setColumns; i++) {
      $("<td>column</td>").appendTo("tr");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Set Rows:
<br>
<input type="text" id="setRows">
<br>Set Columns:
<br>
<input type="text" id="setColumns">

<button type='button' onclick='myForm();'>Create Table</button>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
```

A few pointers going forward:

You can skip the "myForm" function, and instead put your variables just inside the ready-function.

You're also binding "button" to two things: to run myForm and to create your table. Removing the myForm-function, like stated above, obviously means you can remove the "onclick" event. But even if you keep the function, the call to "myForm" would be better placed inside the ready-function.

Answer (score 0):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/dehove/1/edit?html,js,console,output)***

```
<button type='button'>Create Table</button>
```

It's quite slow to append elements inside a for loop,
instead create a HTML representation of your table, and append it only once you're done  generating it:

```
$("button").click(function(){

  var setRows    = +$("#setRows").val();    // Value to Number using Unary +
  var setColumns = +$("#setColumns").val();

  // THE HTML STRING
  var table = "<table>";   

  // OUTER FOR LOOP : ROWS
  for (var i=0; i<setRows; i++){

        // START THE TR
        table += "<tr>";

        // INNER FOR LOOP :: CELLS INSIDE THE TR
        for (var j = 0; j < setColumns; j++) {
              table += "<td>column</td>";
        }

        // CLOSE THE TR
        table += "</tr>";
  }

  // CLOSE THE TABLE
  table += "</table>";

  // APPEND ONLY ONCE
  $("p:last").after(table);

});
```

As you see above I've used a `for` loop inside another `for` loop cause:

```
<tr>                               <!-- OUTER FOR LOOP (rows)    -->
    <td>column</td><td>column</td> <!-- INNER FOR LOOP (cells) -->
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){       
        var setRows = $('#setRows').val(); // get your variables inside the click handler so they are available within the scope of your function 
        var setColumns  = $('#setColumns').val(); 
        var rows=[]; // create an array to hold the rows
        for (var r = 0; r < setRows; r++){ // run a loop creating each row
          var cols=[]; // create an array to hold the cells
          for (var c = 0; c < setColumns; c++){// run a loop creating each cell
              cols.push('<td>column</td>'); // push each cell into our array
          }
          rows.push('<tr>'+cols.join('')+'</tr>'); // join the cells array to create this row 
        }
        $('<table>'+rows.join('')+'</table>').insertAfter("p:last"); // join all of the rows, wrap in a table tag, then add to page

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Set Rows:<br>
        <input type="text" id="setRows" value="4"/>
        <br>
        Set Columns:<br>
        <input type="text" id="setColumns" value="5"/>

    <button type="button" id="myBtn" >Create Table</button>
    <p id = "demo1"></p>
    <p id = "demo2"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a nested loop (as others have suggested).

Also when creating elements using jQuery - you don't have to specify both opening and closing tags - `$("<elem />")` works nicely..

Snippet:

```js
$(function () {

    var go = $("#go");
    var cols = $("#columns");
    var rows = $("#rows")

    go.click(function () {

        var numRows = rows.val();
        var numCols = cols.val();
        var table = $("<table />");
        var head = $("<thead />");
        var row = $("<tr />");

        // build header
        var headRow = row.clone();
        for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
            var th = $("<th />");
            th.append(i);
            headRow.append(th);
        }

        table.append(headRow);

        // build table
        for (var j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
            var addRow = row.clone();
            for (var k = 0; k < numCols; k++) {
                var cell = $('<td />');
                cell.css({"border":"solid 2px teal"});
                cell.append("<p>R:" + j + " |C:" + k + "</p>");
                addRow.append(cell);
            }
            table.append(addRow);
        }
        
        $('body').append(table);

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Rows:</label>
<input id="rows" />
<label>Columns:</label>
<input id="columns" />
<button id="go">Go!</button>
```